# Merging two data frames that are not the same dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 based on 'Code' and 'Race Number'. However, as you can see these dataframes are not the same dimension. I would like to merge these dataframes so the rows in dataframe 1 that do not match with dataframe 2 are retained. I have provided an example of my desired output below.

It should be noted that not every race has a track condition and sometimes the track condition can change from race to race.

Code for dataframes:

```
cols1 = ['Code', 'Date', 'Venue', 'Race Number', 'Distance', 'Race Time']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=cols1)
df.to_excel("test1.xlsx")
cols2 = ['Code', 'Race Number', 'Track Condition']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=cols2)
```

Output of dataframe 1:

```
       Code                 Date Venue  Race Number  Distance Race Time
0   5162548  2020-11-28T13:15:00  WMAI            1      1708   1:52.83
1   5162548  2020-11-28T13:50:00  WMAI            2      1508   1:37.34
2   5162548  2020-11-28T14:25:00  WMAI            3      1608   1:43.89
3   5162548  2020-11-28T14:55:00  WMAI            4      1008   1:02.54
4   5162548  2020-11-28T15:25:00  WMAI            5      1008   1:02.18
5   5162548  2020-11-28T15:55:00  WMAI            6      1008   1:01.94
```

Output of dataframe 2:

```
      Code  Race Number Track Condition
0  5162548            1          Good 4
```

Desired output of merged dataframe:

```
      Code                 Date Venue  Race Number  Distance Race Time Track Condition
0  5162548  2020-11-28T13:15:00  WMAI           1      1708   1:52.83          Good 4
2  5162548  2020-11-28T14:25:00  WMAI           3      1608   1:43.89           Empty
3  5162548  2020-11-28T14:55:00  WMAI           4      1008   1:02.54           Empty
4  5162548  2020-11-28T15:25:00  WMAI           5      1008   1:02.18           Empty
5  5162548  2020-11-28T15:55:00  WMAI           6      1008   1:01.94           Empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer merge can give the result

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Code', 'Race Number'], how='outer')
df['Track Condition']= df['Track Condition'].fillna('Empty')
```